# Bind Soap Webservice to specific Source port

Tags: java, web-services, networking, port

I have created a SOAP Webservice.
I want to keep the port from which data will be sent through this service , constant.

As of now , the port keeps on changing. When I go to command prompt and execute following command:

`netstat -a -n -o | find "32032"`

[image: Command prompt screentshot]

As you can see in the image the port is changing after every few seconds. `32032` is the process id of my service.

How do I stop port number from changing?